# Titanium local notification

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an app that retrieves data from remote (custom REST API). For this I would like to implement local notification instead of push notification. The aim is to display notifications (iOS and Android) when something is happening from remote (let's say a new offer is available).

So before coding I have some questions:

- Could I display data from remote as a local notification?
- Do both Android and iOS support this?
- What exactly is the difference between local and push notification

Answer (score 3):

You can use local notification on both platforms:

- Android: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Notification
- iOS: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.LocalNotification

To display remote data you need to have it first. Which means you have to make an API call to your server and receive the data. So your app needs to have a background service:

- iOS: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Background_Services
- Android: https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager

Again, both platforms support this.

If you want to implement this as a local notification you should already know what it does :) But since you want to get remote data I would use push notifications because with the background service you need to ask the server all the time if there is something new and then display your notification. With a push notification you could just send out the push to the phones and then show a notification.

There is a great CommonJS module that helps you to implement push on both platforms: https://github.com/HazemKhaled/TiPushNotification

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response, clear and complete but let me ask another question about it :

- Push notification is attached by the device Id, it means when user creates an account on my app, device id is sent to database to receive notification.

The problem is, when this same person use another device without creating account but only to consult news ... he cannot get push, or i am wrong?

Comment: correct. You have to register this device again. But you could check if the username wants to receive push notifications and if the user tokes is different just add it. But thats up to you how you want to handle same users with different phones

Comment: Hello thanks again, i don't understand what you mean by : "But you could check if the username wants to receive push notifications and if the user tokes is different just add it".

do you mean "token" ? and the "just add it" really means what?, thanks again.

Comment: When you register a device for push you'll receive a token from the device that you put inside your db. When you send out a push message you use this token to send the push message to. So now you have a token stored next to your user inside your db. When an existing user logs in with a different phone he has a different token. But you know from the username that you have an existing user but with a different token. You can now override the old token or store both.